# exceptionCaught() only catches a few errors - DefaultChannelPipeline warns about uncaught errors

Tags: java, netty

Netty complains about uncaught `DecoderException` exceptions, and even though I catch some of these with my handler, I obviously do not catch all:

```
2020-09-30 19:55:38.952 [Netty-NioEventLoop-Thread-1] WARN  i.n.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:472)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
```

My setup is a bit complex, but here are the main gists

The channel setup in `SecuredChannelInitializer` sets up an SSL handler on the pipeline

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(final SocketChannel socketChannel) {
    final var pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(socketChannel.alloc()));

    pipeline.addLast(createProtocolNegotiationHandler());
}
```

This calls out to

```
private ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler createProtocolNegotiationHandler() {
    return new ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler(HTTP_1_1) {
        @Override
        protected void configurePipeline(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String protocol) {
            final var pipeline = ctx.pipeline();

            addProtocolHandlers(protocol, pipeline);
            applicationPipelineInitializer.addHandlersToPipeline(pipeline);
        }
```

This last step adds a bunch of handlers

```
@Override
public void addHandlersToPipeline(final ChannelPipeline pipeline) {
    pipeline.addLast(
            new HttpLoggerHandler(),
            connectionErrorHandler, 
            ...
```

So this basically boils down to a pipeline that consists of

- ssl handler
- protocol handlers (http 1 / 2)
- http logger
- connection error handler (implements `exceptionCaught`)

The connection error handler looks like this:

```
@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    if (isDevelopment && (cause instanceof SSLHandshakeException || cause instanceof DecoderException))  {
        logger.debug("SSL handshake exceptions. Ignored in development, as self-signed certificates are common");
    } else {
        ctx.fireExceptionCaught(cause);
    }
}
```

This does get called, but very seldom! There are quite a few errors like above buzzing by, but every now and then this might get called, so it seems like two different things. It almost seems like we are talking about two different pipelines, but I do not see how that is possible. When setting a breakpoing in `DefaultChannelPipeline`, I can see that it is for the same port as I set up above. I tried inspecting the objects for the pipeline connected to `DefaultChannelPipeline` in the debugger, but could not really tell if the pipeline was the same as the one I had setup.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple flows within a pipeline. An inbound and outbound flow. Does your error handler handle both inbound and outbound errors that aren't handled by anything else?
Are you sure that your pipeline ordering is correct? The error handler must be at the end of both inbound and outbound processing. See https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html#addLast-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler
For details of "How an event flows in a pipeline"